# python check if word is in certain elements of a list

Tags: python, list, cpu-word

I was wondering if there was a better way to put:

```
if word==wordList[0] or word==wordList[2] or word==wordList[3] or word==worldList[4]
```

Comment: loop over the list and check them that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple task, and so many ways to deal with it. Exciting! Here is what I think:

If you know for sure that wordList is small (else it might be too inefficient), then I recommend using this one:

```
b = word in (wordList[:1] + wordList[2:])
```

---

Otherwise I would *probably* go for this (still, it depends!):

```
b = word in (w for i, w in enumerate(wordList) if i != 1)
```

For example, if you want to ignore several indexes:

```
ignore = frozenset([5, 17])
b = word in (w for i, w in enumerate(wordList) if i not in ignore)
```

This is pythonic and it scales.

---

However, there are noteworthy alternatives:

```
### Constructing a tuple ad-hoc. Easy to read/understand, but doesn't scale.
# Note lack of index 1.
b = word in (wordList[0], wordList[2], wordList[3], wordList[4])

### Playing around with iterators. Scales, but rather hard to understand.
from itertools import chain, islice
b = word in chain(islice(wordList, None, 1), islice(wordList, 2, None))

### More efficient, if condition is to be evaluated many times in a loop.
from itertools import chain
words = frozenset(chain(wordList[:1], wordList[2:]))
b = word in words
```

Comment: I ended up using the frozenset() method, thank you! The original way I did it threw an error because it was a list of lists, but this works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

```
word in wordList
```

Or, if you want to check the 4 first,

```
word in wordList[:4]
```

Comment: i was hoping for something like "word in wordList" but I want to ignore the second element.

Comment: @Sam: `word in wordList[0] + wordList[2:]` is the most succint way. Just be aware that it creates a new list object, so if your list is expensive, it would be better to iterate. However, the fact that you're skipping an element tells me each index means something; why don't you use another collection type? `namedtuple`? A custom class with `__contains__`?

Comment: Thank you, Daenyth! I'm still new to the language, but I'll have to look into creating a structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have indexList be a list of the indicies you want to check (ie, `[0,2,3]`) and have wordList be all the words you want to check. Then, the following command will return the 0th, 2nd, and 3rd elements of wordList, as a list:

```
[wordList[i] for i in indexList]
```

This will return `[wordList[0], wordList[2], wordList[3]]`.