# else statement not executing

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-logic

The part of my code where I ask the user if they want some cake has me confused.

```
import time
print("Here comes dat boi")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Waddup dat boi")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("Whats your name?\n")
print ("Hello,",name)
time.sleep(.5)
cake = input("Hello, want some cake?\n")
if cake == 'yes' or 'ya' or 'Ya':
    print("Cool!")
else:
    print('Aww..')
```

Sample Input:

```
ya
yes
no
something other
```

Expected Output:

```
Cool!
Cool!
Aww..
Aww..
```

Actual Output

```
Cool!
Cool!
Cool!
Cool!
```

Why is the line `print('Aww..')` not executing?

Answer (score 2):

An if statement is built on conditions. If you plan to use a statement with multiple different 'triggers' you must state the new conditions for each.

As such, your statement requires `cake ==` for every potential true or false outcome.

```
import time
print("Here comes dat boi")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Waddup dat boi")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("Whats your name?\n")
print ("Hello,",name)
time.sleep(.5)
cake = input("Hello, want some cake?\n")
if cake == 'yes' or cake == 'ya' or cake == 'Ya':
    print("Cool!")
else:
    print('Aww..')
```

To help with your confusion, I believe the `or 'ya' or 'Ya'` resulted in true due to both the user input and 'ya'/'Ya' being of the string type.

*Do not quote me on that last part. My assumption may be incorrect.*

Edit: Your comment "
Isaac It probably works but the or should hook them up. It was working earlier. It will work with one word but if not it will all ways say Cool!" suggests that my assumption regarding the type match resulting in true is in fact correct. That could be why earlier testing could have made the `or` seem like it was hooking the different possibilities.

The following code `if cake in ('yes', 'Ya','ya'):` would be the correct method of 'hooking' the different possibilities into a single condition.

Fixed Answer for OP:

```
import time
print("Here comes dat boi")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Waddup dat boi")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("Whats your name?\n")
print ("Hello,",name)
time.sleep(.5)
cake = input("Hello, want some cake?\n")
if cake in ('yes', 'Ya','ya', 'fine', 'sure'):
    print("Cool!")
else:
    print('Aww..')
```

Comment: Thanks! Earlier I got it to go cake == 'ya' or 'yes' or 'Ya' did I screw something up?

Comment: I've updated my answer with reasoning for it working earlier and a method for you to check if a single variable is equal to one of multiple responses :)

Comment: I tried the "in" method but It didn't work. When I respond no it will still say Cool!

Comment: Would I be able to see your code for that? I've tested it on my system and it all seems to work. Please note that I am using Python 3.5.2

Comment: I am using the same and sure you can see it!                                                                               import time
print("Here comes dat boi")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Waddup dat boi")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("Whats your name?\n")
print ("Hello,",name)
time.sleep(.5)
cake = input("Hello, want some cake?\n")
if cake in 'yes' or 'ok' or 'fine' or 'sure':
    print("Cool!")
else:
    print('Aww..')

Comment: Ah, you've forgotten to add parenthesis around the potential answers :) Please check the last line of my answer for the correct syntax for usage of `in`.

Comment: I forgot commas! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I've added the full python code to my answer :) I hope it can help

Comment: I'm glad I could help solve your problem! :) Can I recommend accepting one of the answers given to you as it'll help others with the same issue see the correct method of fixing it! :) @stallion093

Answer (score 1):

I haven't written a single line of python before, but my intuition says you need to replace

```
if cake == 'yes' or 'ya' or 'Ya':
```

with

```
if cake == 'yes' or cake == 'ya' or cake == 'Ya':
```

---

You could try [Word in array of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659494/python-check-if-word-is-in-certain-elements-of-a-list) (again, untested, just a guess)

```
if cake in ['yes','ya','Ya']:
```

Comment: Isaac It probably works but the or should hook them up. It was working earlier. It will work with one word but if not it will all ways say Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Non-empty strings are always evaluated as `True` in Python. Your code

```
if cake == 'yes' or 'ya' or 'Ya':
```

, using boolean logic, will always execute the tasks under it no matter you enter there. So it always prints "Cool!".

To prevent this from happening you should modify your conditional `if` statement in such a way that you will only catch the words `'yes'`, `'ya'` and `'Ya'`. Thus, `if cake == 'yes' or 'ya' or 'Ya':` should be replaced with

```
if cake == 'yes' or cake == 'ya' or cake == 'Ya':
```

or if you are already familiar with Python lists

```
if cake in ['yes', 'ya', 'Ya']: # Evaluates to True if cake is 
                                # equivalent to one of the strings in the list
```

Read this [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/python-truth-value-of-python-string) for more details on the truth value of a Python string.